# How to Lock/Hide Virtual Desktop on windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-11, multitasking

I have "leisue" virtual desktop(windows + tab) on my windows 11, I want to lock it/hide it. So it is not easy to get into it.Is this option possible?

Comment: Hide from where? From the win+tab overview? And could you please include what [your own research](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) has brought you so far?

Comment: Hide from the win + tab overdue. Or lock it when going there.

Comment: Ok, and what about your own research?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the use of the virtual desktops basically or do you need to spin one up with custom stuff and then prevent it from being accessible from that same WIndows logged on profile?

Comment: I need to spin one up with custom stuff and then prevent it from being accessible from that same WIndows logged on profile.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle exactly what you said spin one up with custom stuff and then prevent it from being accessible from that same WIndows logged on profile.